# How to generate Auto increment id like 1.1,1.2 based on parent row in Nested grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I want to generate nested grid view from grid view row add button.if i click add button nested grid view have to be generate based on parent grid ID.

For example parent grid id=1 means while clicking add nested grid row have to be generated with auto increment ID while each time clicking add button(like 1.1,1.2) If second row from parent grid means 2.1,2.2 like this have to create in nested grid row id

One solution is have to use MAX query to auto increment.

## Tried

while clicking add in grid view row:
using two tables while concatenating 1.1,1.2 for first row.if i add in second row it showing 2.3 how to solve. using data table is easy means how to do it?

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string Sid = GridState.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO City  VALUES('" + TextBox3.Text + "' , '" + TextBox4.Text + "' , '" + TextBox5.Text+"' , " + Sid+")", con))
                {

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                    string sQuery1 = "SELECT CAST(S_id AS VARCHAR(20) ) +'.'+ CAST(City_id AS VARCHAR(20) ),City_code,City_name from City where S_id="+Sid;
                    string value=getData1(sQuery1).ToString();
                    //string sQuery = "SELECT CAST(S_id AS VARCHAR(20) ) +'.'+ CAST(City_id AS VARCHAR(20) ),City_code,City_name from City";
                    ////GridView City = e.Equals("GridCity") as GridView;

                    //GridState.DataSource = getData(sQuery);
                    //GridState.DataBind();

                }

            }
```

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ This is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: As for the question at hand....I don't understand what you are trying to do at all.

Comment: thank you,but what is the solution

Comment: just add auto increment id(1.1,1.2...) based on parent id(1) in nested grid view.

Comment: If you really want some help you need to provide some details. It is clear to you what you want but I don't know anything about your project and your description of the problem is not clear to me at all. Maybe you should look here for improving your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: nothing big,auto increment id based on another id,that's it...If one id=1(row),while clicking add button in that row another sub row have to be created with automatic id(1.1)......how to do it?

Comment: There are LOTS of ways this could be done. And they all vary depending on your tables and the details which you don't want to share. You seem to want somebody else to do all the work and you sit back and wait for a solution. That is not how this works. We are not here as a code writing service. How about the table definition? Some sample data? The basic things needed for this type of question. Try reading the link I sent to improve your question.

Comment: just give a method how to do it pls

Comment: No. I am not going to spend a bunch of time to come up with one way to do this that probably is not going to work for you. If you were paying me by the hour I would be happy to do this. But as a volunteer offering to help somebody who clearly is not interested in putting in any effort I wish you the best. I truly hope you can find a solution. But if you need help from others you need to be part of the solution.